# Porque meu border-image não respeita o border-radius?

Tags: css, css3, css-border, css-border-radius

Estou usando uma `linear-gradient` como `border-imagem` em um elemento, mas dessa forma a borda não respeita o `border-radius` que coloquei e não realiza a curvatura nos vértices.

**Eu gostaria que ficasse assim:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Mas está ficando assim:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui está o código referente a imagem acima. Deixei o `box-shadow` para vcs verem que o elemento `.box` está com o `border-radius` funcionando corretamente, mas o `border-imagem` não respeita esse `border-radius` e continua sem realizar curvatura nos vértices.

***Como posso corrigir isso?*** *(sem ser com SVG)*

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 160px;
  margin: auto; 
  border: 2px solid;
  border-image: linear-gradient(red, blue);
  border-image-slice: 1;
  border-radius: 20px;

  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px green;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá, tudo bem?

Tente a seguinte abordagem, por favor:

Já tive o mesmo problema algum tempo atrás e formulei minha solução com base neste tópico https://gist.github.com/stereokai/36dc0095b9d24ce93b045e2ddc60d7a0

Simplifiquei a edição da resposta, foi utilizado o border com double para duplicar a espessura e transparent para inibir a cor default. Desta forma utilizamos via background-image as novas cores, sendo que o linear-gradient contempla o preenchimento interno da  e o radial-gradient (podendo ser aqui também linear, como preferir) fica responsável pela cor da borda,  Background-origin com border-box define a área de posicionamento do plano de fundo. O Background-clip: content-box., o fundo é desenhado dentro (cortado) a caixa de conteúdo, já border-box também aplicado aqui, o fundo se extende até fora da fronteira da borda (mas por baixo da borda na ordenação-z). Espero ter ajudado.

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 160px;
  margin: auto; 
  border: double 2px transparent;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(white, white), radial-gradient(circle at top left, red, blue);
  background-origin: border-box;
  background-clip: content-box, border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Amigo seria interessante vc colocar detalhes do que fez, apesar de parece correto eu não entendi o que foi feito e não quero dar só um crtl+c/v sem entender o que foi feito ai. Se vc copiou o código de algum lugar seria interessante vc citar a fonte

Comment: Simplifiquei a edição da resposta, foi utilizado o border com double para duplicar a espessura e transparent para inibir a cor default. Desta forma utilizamos via background-image as novas cores, sendo que o linear-gradient contempla o preenchimento interno da <div> e o radial-gradient fica responsávle pela cor da borda. Background-origin com border-box define a área de posicionamento do plano de fundo. Espero ter ajudado :)

Comment: Desculpe amigo mas continuei sem entender... Porque radial-gradient e não o linear-gradiente? E o background-clip não serve pra nada? Seria interessante vc adicionar uma explicação no campo da resposta e não aqui no comentário, acho que fica melhor para quem tiver a mesma dúvida poder ver direito sem precisa ler os comments aqui

Comment: Sim amigo, vou editar novamente e tentar abordar uma explicação mais coerente, obrigado pelo feedback, espero poder ajudar.